# Chart showing returns by asset class vs CAGR

Tags: asset-allocation, compound-interest

I know of charts that show yearly returns by asset class.

Are there charts that show 10 year *CAGR* by asset class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Portfolio Asset Class Allocation](https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-asset-class-allocation) can do this for you.